# How to understand the difference between reactor.util.retry.Retry#backoff and reactor.util.retry.Retry#fixedDelay?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

i tried the fixedDelay and backoff,is seems to be same... so what`s the difference of Them and the usage of them.

```java
 static AtomicInteger retryTime = new AtomicInteger();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        generate()
                .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(5, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                        .filter(e -> e instanceof Exception)
                        .doBeforeRetry(res -> System.out.println("retry begin"))
                        .doAfterRetry(res -> System.out.println("try finished")))
                .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> System.out.println(throwable))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    private static Mono<String> generate() {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            if (retryTime.get() == 3) {
                return "Hello";
            }
            System.out.println("i am called" + retryTime.getAndAdd(1));
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("exception test");
        });
    }
```

Comment: backoff() utilises a minimum delay of x seconds between each request, whereas fixedDelay() uses the same delay of x seconds

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the deprecated docs from `Mono.retryBackoff()` were a bit better:

> The randomized exponential backoff is good at
> preventing two typical issues with other simpler backoff strategies,
> namely:
>
> - having an exponentially growing backoff delay with a small
>   initial delay gives the best tradeoff between not overwhelming the
>   server and serving the client as fast as possible
> - having a jitter, or
>   randomized backoff delay, is beneficial in avoiding "retry-storms"
>   where eg. numerous clients would hit the server at the same time,
>   causing it to display transient failures which would cause all clients
>   to retry at the same backoff times, ultimately sparing no load on the
>   server.